# Executing class instance method that is in an array (javascript)

Tags: javascript

EDIT: Solved by renaming the `this.powerOn` declaration in all of the class constructors.

I have a function that pulls data from a database and stores it in the appropriate array(s). I have another function that iterates through said array(s) and instantiates a new instance of a class based on a targeted property & these instances are stored in a separate array. I am having trouble triggering methods of said instances that, as far as I can tell, should be apart of them.

Currently this is how I am attempting to handle this:

```
const SourceModel = require('../models/Source');
const DisplayModel = require('../models/Display');
const Roku = require('../_data/sdk/Roku');
const Sony = require('../_data/sdk/Sony');
 
const driversArray = [];
const liveDriverInstances = [];
 
// Returns new class instance based on DriverModel
class instantiatedDriverClass {
  constructor(DriverModel, DriverIPAddress, DriverPort) {
    let driverClasses = {
      Roku,
      Sony
    };
    return new driverClasses[DriverModel](DriverIPAddress, DriverPort)
  }
}
 
// Pull sources, displays, ..., from DB
const getDevicesFromDB = async () => {
  sourcesArray = await SourceModel.find();
  displaysArray = await DisplayModel.find();
};
 
// Create new array from sources, displays, ..., arrays & iterate to instantiate matching driver class
const loadDeviceDriversToRuntime = async () => {
  await getDevicesFromDB();
  sourcesArray.forEach((source) => driversArray.push(source));
  displaysArray.forEach((display) => driversArray.push(display));
  driversArray.forEach((driver) => {
    liveDriverInstances.push(new instantiatedDriverClass(driver.driver.driverModel, driver.ipaddress, driver.port));
  });
};
 
// Executed by server after connection to DB is established
const importDrivers = () => {
  loadDeviceDriversToRuntime();
}
 
module.exports = importDrivers, driversArray;
```

The two classes (so far) that I am trying to execute methods on are Roku and Sony. Roku extends MediaPlayer and Sony extends Display. MediaPlayer and Display extends Commands. Code for Roku class:

```
const MediaPlayer = require('./MediaPlayer');

class Roku extends MediaPlayer {
  constructor(ipaddress, port, powerOnDelay, powerOffDelay) {
    super();
    let url = `https://${ipaddress}:${port}`
    this.powerOn = `${url}/powerOn`;
    this.powerOff = `${url}/powerOff`;
    this.up = `${url}/up;`
    this.down = `${url}/down`;
    this.left = `${url}/left`;
    this.right = `${url}/right`;
    this.enter = `${url}/enter`;
    this.select = `${url}/select`;
    this.back = `${url}/back`;
    this.backspace = `${url}/backspace`;
    this.exit = `${url}/exit`;
    this.guide = `${url}/guide`;
    this.menu = `${url}/menu`;
  }

  powerOn() {
    super.powerOn(this.powerOn);
  }

  powerOff() {
    super.powerOff(this.powerOff);
  }
}

module.exports = Roku;
```

Code for MediaPlayer class:

```
const Commands = require('./Commands');

class MediaPlayer extends Commands {
  constructor(powerOn, powerOff, up, down, left, right, enter, select, back, backspace, exit, guide, menu) {
    super();
    this.powerOn = powerOn;
    this.powerOff = powerOff;
    this.up = up;
    this.down = down;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.enter = enter;
    this.select = select;
    this.back = back;
    this.backspace = backspace;
    this.exit = exit;
    this.guide = guide;
    this.menu = menu;
  }

  powerOn() {
    super.powerOn(this.powerOn);
  }

  powerOff() {
    super.powerOff(this.powerOff);
  }
}

module.exports = MediaPlayer;
```

Code for Commands class:

```
class Commands {
  constructor(command) {
    this.command = command;
  }
  powerOn(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  powerOff(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  up(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  down(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  left(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  right(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  enter(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  play(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  pause(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  select(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  guide(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  menu(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  back(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  delete(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  speed1(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  speed2(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  speed3(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  HDMI1(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  HDMI2(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
  HDMI3(command) {
    console.log("Something")
  }
}

module.exports = Commands;
```

As far as I understand, the methods `powerOn()` and `powerOff()` should be accessible when an instance of Roku or Sony is created. If, however, I try to do something like `liveDriverInstances[0].powerOn()` I get an error `liveDriverInstances[0].powerOn is not a function`. When I run `console.log(liveDriverInstances[0])` I get this response:

```
Roku {
    command: undefined,
    powerOn: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/powerOn',
    powerOff: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/powerOff',
    up: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/up;',
    down: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/down',
    left: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/left',
    right: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/right',
    enter: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/enter',
    select: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/select',
    back: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/back',
    backspace: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/backspace',
    exit: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/exit',
    guide: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/guide',
    menu: 'https://192.168.1.205:8060/menu'
}
```

So the data is being passed down from the Roku instance inheriting from MediaPlayer inheriting from Commands, but I don't have the methods. Looks like it is just getting the constructor method, but nothing more. Have I defined something incorrectly here?

Comment: It looks like you are overriding the functions with variable declarations in the constructor of `Roku`, which is likely not helping.

Comment: To test this in the Roku class I changed `this.powerOn` to `this.powerOnCommand`, but running `liveDriverInstances[0].powerOn()` still returns the same error

Comment: @msbit Actually you did get me going here, changing the `this.powerOn` declaration to `this.powerOnCommand` in the `Roku` class was only the start, I had to change it in the `MediaPlayer` and `Commands` classes as well. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the constructor of `Roku` class. you are initializing the `powerOn` as a `String` . This will replace the function `powerOn()` declared.

```
constructor(ipaddress, port, powerOnDelay, powerOffDelay) {
    ...
    this.powerOn = `${url}/powerOn`;
     ...
}
```

You can make this work by renaming the url fields

```
constructor(ipaddress, port, powerOnDelay, powerOffDelay) {
    ...
    this.powerOnUrl = `${url}/powerOn`;
     ...
}

powerOn() {
     super.powerOn(this.powerOnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Yup another commenter pointed that out, silly mistake on my part. I had to rename all of the `this.` declarations in the `Roku`, `MediaPlayer`, and `Commands` classes.